# Prevent Comments from Parsing

Tags: php, html, browser

Is there a way to hide commenting in my php/html file?

I want to add markup that I don't want people to be able to view in source in their browsers.

Is this possible?

```
<!-- Prevent this comment from being viewed -->
<?php...
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "hide commenting"? Can you make an example? What kind of markup do you want to add?

Comment: Ehm, you need to learn how PHP works. The file isn't sent to the client, it is "executed" and the _result_ is sent to the browser. PHP comments do not result in anything, thus they are not sent to the browser. And if you want to add markup that is sent to the browser but not visible within the browser, that's just like totally not gonna be possible...

Comment: You can't hide HTML comments (`<!-- .. -->`), but PHP comments (`/* .. */` and `// ..`) are of course hidden. Oh and read up on how client-server works (and how PHP is a server language).

Comment: Thanks Pekka.  And Peter, so you're saying I'm not processing the PHP in my browser? hehehe...

Comment: Thanks Peter. And Christian...  Question answered!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you add comments as PHP, people won't see it in their browser.

```
<div> 
   <!-- This HTML comment can be seen by people -->
   <?php //But this PHP comment can only be seen by me :) ?>
</div>
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP

Comment: Thanks John!  This is how I had done it so far...  I was curious if there was a different solution.  Solves that question!

Answer (score 0):

I see what you mean. You can do that with output buffering:

```
<?php
   // this is not
?><!-- this is sent to browser -->
```

And with output buffering.

```
<?php

   ob_start();

   ?><!-- this is NOT sent to browser --> <b>This isn't sent as well!</b> <?php

   ob_end_clean();
?>
```

However, if you want to remove comments *only*, you need to do some parsing:

```
<?php

   ob_start();

   ?><!-- this is NOT sent to browser --><?php

   $html=ob_get_clean();

   // TODO: Use a DOM parser to parse $html and remove comments from it.

?>
```

That does sound a bit over-engineered though...

Comment: It all depends on implementation. For example, if you had full control of the comments, I'd add a comment ID and do a regex replace - much faster than DOM parsing (eg: `<!-- $1$ Comemnt 1... --> ... <!-- $2$ Another comment... -->`)

Answer (score 0):

Just swap lines above and use php comment:

```
<?php...
// Prevented this comment from being viewed
```